# Wondering why the induction method of proof is meant to prove something.

Tags: calculus, proof-writing, soft-question

One thing I find weird is induction proof, I understand how to use it fully and it's not that it is hard, it's just that it doesn't come across as actual "proof".
Let me give you an example:

I was trying to prove the binomial theorem today,

$$
(a+b)^n=
\begin{equation}
\sum_{j=0}^{n} \binom{n}{j}a^{n-j}b^j
\end{equation}
$$

In a nutshell, I spent $30$ minutes trying to find a (satisfactory - at least to me if that makes sense) proof without realizing that the question was asking for an induction proof which when I found out, I easily came to the answer, but that's not the point, the point is that the answer (that I and the book came to) was

> For ($a+b)^1$ or $n=1$, the binomial theorem is clear.  No question there.
>
> For $(a+b)^{n+1}$, we get
>
> $$
> (a+b)^{n+1}=
> \begin{equation}
> \sum_{j=0}^{n+1} \binom{n+1}{j}a^{(n+1)-j}b^j    
> \end{equation}
> $$

My question is, from this proof, how can we still be satisfied that $n=n+1$ clears the theorem? Thank you.

P.S. I am not sure if I made it very obvious, but $\binom{n}{j}$ is a binomial coefficient.

---

Comment: You mean $(a+b)^{n\color{blue}{+1}}=\sum_{j=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{j}a^{(n+1)-j}b^j$. On the right-hand side, presumably $n+1$ is bracketed in $(n+1)-j$ to emphasize how we get that exponent. The point is to show that if one case is right, then so is the next. Is your question about how to prove that if/then statement, or more generally about why proving it (and the base step!) is enough to prove the general case?

Comment: Induction works because first you show it holds for some base case $P(0)$. Then *if* you can show $P(n) \implies P(n+1)$, then we conclude $P(0) \implies P(1)$, then $P(1) \implies P(2)$ and so on for all $n$. It's that second implication that allows you to bootstrap upwards because you can apply it to the base case to conclude non-base cases.

Comment: @Sdavid552 No, you can't because just replacing n to n+1 doesn't keep the statement true. What you do is *assume* the n-case then with other manipulations, try to derive the n+1-case. In doing so you prove the implication $P(n) \implies P(n+1)$

Comment: hmm, can you write out what your complete argument was for the $n+1$ case? right now you have not given an induction argument there. that the statement holds for $n+1$ does not pop out immediately in the way that you've written; there are some non-trivial calculations that you need to make to reduce it to the $n$ case (which is the induction hypothesis)

Comment: @Sdavid552 An excellent question. It comes down to the fact that the naturals are well-ordered: i.e., every non-empty subset of naturals has a least element. So, suppose we take the subset of the naturals consisting of all $n$ for which the statement is false. If that set is empty, there exist a least element. Then, the element $-1$ satisfies the conditions, so induction proves that the minimal element does too, a contradiction.

Comment: No-one has stated this explicitly yet, so for the sake of people who read your question in the future: what you have written is __not__ a valid induction proof. I believe the OP realizes that now, and the answer by J.G. show what a valid proof looks like, but I though someone should note this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments have clarified that the question is how we separate true consequences of induction from false ones. A valid proof needs two ingredients: the base step must be shown to work, and so must the inductive step.

The base step here is $(a+b)^0=\sum_{j=0}^0\binom{0}{j}a^{n-j}b^j$, which simplifies to $1=1$ so is true. With the inductive step, it helps to use slightly different notation: show if the case $n=k$ works so does the case $n=k+1$. In this problem, this looks like$$\begin{align}(a+b)^{k+1}&=(a+b)(a+b)^k\\&=(a+b)\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}a^{k-j}b^j\\&=\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}a^{k+1-j}b^j+\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}a^{k-j}b^{j+1}\\&=\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}a^{k+1-j}b^j+\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}a^{k+1-(j+1)}b^{j+1}\\&=\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}a^{k+1-j}b^j+\sum_{j=1}^{k+1}\binom{k}{j-1}a^{k+1-j}b^j\\&=\sum_{j=0}^{k+1}\binom{k}{j}a^{k+1-j}b^j+\sum_{j=0}^{k+1}\binom{k}{j-1}a^{k+1-j}b^j\\&=\sum_{j=0}^{k+1}\left(\binom{k}{j}+\binom{k}{j-1}\right)a^{k+1-j}b^j\\&=\sum_{j=0}^{k+1}\binom{k+1}{j}a^{k+1-j}b^j,\end{align}$$where the second $=$ assumes the case $n=k$.

Comment: Hey man, I am sorry for the stupid question overall, it wasn't thought out really well, but I have another stupid question: from lines 5 to 6, how did you change the upper limit and index to be the same? Is that some sort of identity?

Comment: @Sdavid552 It might have been the book that was stupid; I haven't seen it. All I'm doing is adding terms that are $0$, so each sum runs over the same range of values for $j$. Note in particular $\binom{k}{\ell=0}$ whenever $\ell<0$ or $\ell>k$, because then a size-$k$ set has no size-$\ell$ subsets.

Comment: Oh, so you can do illegal things like this? That's amazing, but I don't understand if you mean that terms that have $l<0$ and $l>k$ are $\binom{k}{0}$ which consequently are $1$, or they are binomial coefficients that give off the value $0$. P.S. If $\binom{k}{l}$ where $l>k$, then wouldn't the operation to calculate binomial coefficients include a negative factorial, which would be a complex number, not $0$? Thank you, regardless, for the answer.

Comment: @Sdavid552 Sorry, I missed out an $=0$ in what should have been $\binom{k}{\ell}=0$. But no, there's nothing illegal there. The binomial coefficient is defined as a number of sunsets; the factorial-based formula can be proved for $0\le\ell\le k$, then (if you like, but we don't need it) extended with the convention $1/m! =0$ for $m<0$. (If you're really fancy, this is a zero of the entire function $1/\Gamma(z)$ at $z=m+1$.)

Answer (score 2):

The "proof" of the inductive step is either incomplete or plain wrong. In the correct proof, we should assume:

$$(a+b)^n=\sum_{j=0}^n{n\choose j}a^{n-j}b^j$$

and prove the same for $n+1$, i.e.

$$(a+b)^{n+1}=\sum_{j=0}^{n+1}{{n+1}\choose j}a^{(n+1)-j}b^j$$

This is normally done this way:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}(a+b)^{n+1}&=&(a+b)^n\cdot (a+b)\\&=&\left(\sum_{j=0}^n{n\choose j}a^{n-j}b^j\right)\cdot(a+b)\quad\text{(here we used the inductive hypothesis)}\\&=&\sum_{j=0}^n{n\choose j}a^{n-j+1}b^j+\sum_{j=0}^n{n\choose j}a^{n-j}b^{j+1}\\&=&a^{n+1}+\sum_{j=1}^{n}{n\choose j}a^{n-j+1}b^j+\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}{n\choose j}a^{n-j}b^{j+1}+b^{n+1}\\&=&a^{n+1}+\sum_{j=1}^{n}{n\choose j}a^{n-j+1}b^j+\sum_{j=1}^n{n\choose {j-1}}a^{n-(j-1)}b^j+b^{n+1}\\&=&a^{n+1}+\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left[{n\choose j}+{n\choose {j-1}}\right]a^{(n+1)-j}b^j+b^{n+1}\\&=&a^{n+1}+\sum_{j=1}^{n}{{n+1}\choose j}a^{(n+1)-j}b^j+b^{n+1}\quad\text{(see Note below)}\\&=&\sum_{j=0}^{n+1}{{n+1}\choose j}a^{(n+1)-j}b^j\end{array}$$

**Note**: At the critical place, we used the equality ${n\choose{j-1}}+{n\choose j}={{n+1}\choose j}$ known from combinatorics. We also used the fact that ${n\choose 0}={{n+1}\choose 0}={n\choose n}={{n+1}\choose{n+1}}=1$ liberally throughout the proof.

---

What *seems* to me to have been done in their solution is: just replace $n$ with $n+1$ and - voila, job done. It does not work as simply as that. Replacing $n$ with $n+1$ just converts your *assumption* into your (hopefully) *conclusion*, but you have to connect the two with a sound proof.

Comment: +1 there for remarks at the end.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you have misunderstood what is meant by the induction step.  You seem to think that, in this step, you assume the statement in question, which I'll abbreviate as $P(n)$, for all values of $n$ and then prove it fo $n+1$. That would always work, trivially, by just substituting $n+1$ for $n$ in your assumption.  And it wouldn't actually prove anything about $P(n)$.

But that's not what the induction step is.

The actual induction step assumes $P(n)$ for a single natural number $n$ and tries to prove $P(n+1)$.

Sometimes this is stated, confusingly, as "assume $P(n)$ for an arbitrary $n$", and the word "arbitrary" makes it sound as if you're allowed to assume $P(n)$ for all $n$ at once.  That is not the intended meaning of "arbitrary". The intended meaning is that you're not allowed to assume anything about $n$ beyond its being a natural number satisfying $P(n)$.

So the induction step goes like this. Consider *one*  natural number $n$ about which you assume that $P(n)$ and nothing more. Then try to prove $P(n+1)$.

[To state it more formally, the induction step consists of proving "for all natural numbers $n$, if $P(n)$ then $P(n+1)$."  It does not consist of proving the (trivial but similar-looking) statement "if for all natural numbers $n$ $P(n)$ then $P(n+1)$."  Switching the order of "if" and "for all $n$" makes a huge difference.]